# Crear un subdirectorio en la carpeta Forms de ZF2

Tags: zend

Estoy construyendo un sistema en ZF2, en un `controller` tengo muchos formularios distintos, pero en el mismo modulo tengo muchos `controller` con muchos formularios, y para que quede todo más ordenado quiero crear un subdirectorio en la carpeta `Forms` llamado `Specials` y dejar ahí todos mis formularios especiales, quedando mi estructura de directorios de la siguiente forma

```
module/
Account/
    config/
    Controller/
    Form/
        Specials/
    Model/
    view/
```

En el controlador agrego la línea `use Account\Forms\Specials\SpecialForm1`, luego lo llamo `$special_form1 = new SpecialForm1("form_special1);` pero eso me da el error `not found`

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto por favor.

Comment: Prueba cambiando el namespace Forms por Form.

Comment: Ah! El mismo namespace debe estar también dentro de cada formulario.

Comment: Funciono de inmediato. Dentro de la clase `SpecialForm1` actualice la línea `namespace Account\Forms\Specials;` y funciono de inmediato.

Millón de gracias.

Comment: Lo dejo como respuesta para que sirva a otros usuarios con problemas similares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con una estructura como la planteada, *Zend* construye el `namespace`de cada módulo desde el directorio que hay dentro de `src` (al menos en el esqueleto tradicional).

```
module
├── Account
│   ├── config
│   │   └── module.config.php
│   ├── src
│   │   └── Account
│   │       ├── Controller
│   │       │   └── IndexController.php
│   │       ├── Model
│   │       │   └── MyModel.php
│   │       └── Form
│   │           └── Specials
│   │               └── SpecialForm1.php
│   ├── view
│   │   ├── account
│   │   │   └── index
│   │   │       └── index.phtml
│   │   └── layout
│   │       └── layout.phtml
│   └── Module.php
│...
```

Si simplificamos el esquema hasta la clase que queremos instanciar, en este caso la clase `SpecialForm1`, quedaría así.

```
.
└── Account
    └── Form
        └── Specials
            └── SpecialForm1.php
```

El `namespace` de la clase `SpecialForm1` sería así:

```
namespace Account\Form\Specials;
```

Y para instanciarla desde el controlador podemos usarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
use Account\Form\Specials\SpecialForm1;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // utilizando el namespace del operador use
        $form = new SpecialForm1();
    }
}
```