# Publicar proyecto ZF2 en servidor con Cpanel

Tags: zend

Tengo un proyecto en mi localhost que funciona impecable, subí el proyecto a un servidor cPanel en Hostgator, actualice php a su versión 7.0 para que todo funcione ok, lo subí a una carpeta y cree un subdominio que apunta a la carpeta `public`

Pero cuando ingreso directo al subdominio me da el siguiente error:

> Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving "appscontrollerindex(alias: Apps\Controller\Index)" via invokable class "Apps\Controller\IndexController"; class does not exist

Luego intente ir al controlador de autenticación y me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Users\Model\Users' not found ...
```

-- ACTUALIZACIÓN 1 ---

En el modulo Authentication, así defino el controlador en el archivo `module.config.php` :

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Authentication\Controller\Index' => 'Authentication\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
```

Y en el archivo `IndexController` del modulo Authentication, esta línea incluye la clase Users:

```
use Users\Model\Users;
```

Y después dentro de un action la llamo así:

```
$this->dbAdapter =$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter');
$users = new Users($this->dbAdapter);
```

-- ACTUALIZACIÓN 2 ---

Estuve haciendo todo lo posible porque funcione, me contacte con soporte técnico de  Hostagtor y me dijeron que los planes de reseller y web no son compatibles con ZF2 y por eso no funcionaban. Así que estoy busqe otro servidor que tiene incluso un [instructivo](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215082497-Installing-Zend-Framework-2) para para instalar ZF2

Comment: Generalmente es problema de rutas de puntos de entrada, tal vez esto pueda ayudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140700/zendframework-2-on-cpanel

Comment: 1.- ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de como estableces la configuración de los `controllers` en el `module.config.php`? 2.- ¿Cómo se instancia `Users\Model\Users`?

Comment: @OscarR.  actualice  la publicación.

Comment: @Shaz en ese ejemplo ellos tienen una carpeta llamada `library`, yo tengo una carpeta `vendor`

Comment: Estaba dando por sentado que el servidor funcionaba. Sin `composer` no se levanta la app, y para dar el error del `model` tiene que resolver rutas, módulos y dar con el controlador. De ahí que ni me planteé que fuese eso.

Comment: Según me dijo soporte Hostgator, el servidor no es compatible con ZF2, recien hice una actualización en mi publicación. Perdoón chicquillos era lo primero que tendría que haber hecho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los síntomas apuntan (*por ahora*) a configuración del `getAutoloaderConfig()` dentro de `Module.php`.

Pero esto suele lanzar errores si se usan estructuras de directorios diferentes al clásico `skeleton` y no se ha configurado correctamente.

#### Ejemplo:

---

Estructura Básica

```
module
├── ModuleName
│   ├── config
│   │   └── module.config.php
│   ├── src
│   │   └── ModuleName
│   │       ├── Controller
│   │       │   └── IndexController.php
│   │       └── Model
│   │           └── MyModel.php
│   ├── view
│   └── Module.php
│...
```

Configuración de autoloader en `Module.php`

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return [
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
            'namespaces' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

#### Teoría

---

Por una [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20065/5984) me fijé que tenías la estructura tipo:

```
module
├── ModuleName
│   ├── config
│   │   └── module.config.php
│   ├── Controller
│   │   └── IndexController.php
│   ├── Model
│   │   └── MyModel.php
│   ├── view
│   └── Module.php
│...
```

Por lo que la configuración de autoloader en `Module.php`  debería ser así:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return [
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
            'namespaces' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Creo que deberías revisar la configuración de cada `Module.php` y comprobar que efectivamente apunten correctamente a la estructura para que los `namespaces` respondan adecuadamente.

Coincidiendo con esto, puede ser el motivo por el cual no reconozca el modelo `Users\Model\Users`.

#### Reproducir el error en local

---

Como ejercicio si quieres comprobar el error en la aplicación local que tienes, en cualquier `Module.php` prueba a cambiar:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return [
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
            'namespaces' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Por:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return [
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
            'namespaces' => [
                'OtroNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Debería dar el mismo error por el que estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo la misma estructura básica del `skeleton`, hice el ejercicio pero en el local no me da el error que me da en la web. Ahora estoy con un hosting que permite SSH y he hice la instalación así: `php composer.phar create-project -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application:^2.5`

Subí el modulo usuario solamente para probar y da el mismo error.

Comment: @AlbertBarrientos 2 cosas. 1º ¿esta ruta (`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/‌​bin/php`) usaste para instalar en el _hosting_? --- 2º ¿Probaste antes de subir el módulo usuario si funciona el módulo que trae por defecto? La instalación en limpio de ZF2 debería funcionar antes de empezar a instalar módulos y/o dependencias que puedan causar errores.

Comment: Esa la instale para mi local, en el servidor con `php` solamente.

Creo que encontré el error, estuve copiando línea por línea, y el problema fue una minúscula en una carpeta que sigue de la `src`, la tenia así: `modules/Users/src/users/Controller/IndexController.php` y la carpeta tenia que estar así: `modules/Users/src/Users/Controller/IndexController.php` 

Esta tarde subiré todo el sitio, veré que sucede y les aviso. Mil gracias!

Comment: Funcionó todo, hasta en Hostgator!!!  un millón de gracias @Oscar R.

Comment: @AlbertBarrientos enhorabuena! Me extrañaba lo de Hostgator. Tienes que levantar la aplicación para obtener esos errores. Al tener minúsculas  en la carpeta, el `autoloaderConfig` no reconoce el namespace correctamente por la propia configuracion de la función. Fíjate en el primer ejemplo _Estructura básica_, las dos carpetas van en Mayúsculas para funcionar bien.